# Libgdx 3D model render incorrect using AssetManager

Tags: android, libgdx, 3d-model

I've developed an android application to show some 3d models. Part of 3D models are built using ModelBuilder and part of them exported from Google Sketchup as fbx and converted to g3db to load via AssetManager. The problem is using the mixture of these two methods, models load by AssetManger have been distorted. But using AssetManager to load all models, they rendered just fine. The image in the left is the loading models using AssetManger and the right one is the mixture with ModelBuilder which the model in the bottom got distorted.

[image]
[image]

This is the code I've implemented to load 3D models.

```
@Override
public void create () {
    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    environment = new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
    environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));

    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set(1f, 1f, 1f);
    cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
    cam.near = 1f;
    cam.far = 300f;
    cam.update();

    camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);

    assets = new AssetManager();
    assets.load("data/cylindar.g3db", Model.class);
    loading = true;


}

private void doneLoading() {
    Model model1 = assets.get("data/cylindar.g3db", Model.class);
    ModelInstance modelInstance1 = new ModelInstance(model1); 
    modelInstance1.transform.setToTranslation(-5, -2, 1);
    instances.add(modelInstance1);

    Material material = new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(style.getLayerColor()));
    long attributes = VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal;
    Model model2 = modelBuilder.createSphere(1, 1, 1, 48, 48, material, attributes);
    ModelInstance modelInstance2 = new ModelInstance(model2); 
    modelInstance2.transform.setToTranslation(-8, -2, -3);
    instances.add(modelInstance2);

    loading = false;
}

@Override
public void render () {
    if (loading && assets.update())
        doneLoading();
    camController.update();

    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(instances, environment);
    modelBatch.end();
}
```

Comment: You haven't set the location of the objects, so the cameras near plane is inside the object.

Comment: @Xoppa I've set the objects' location but it didn't resolve the problem. Also in both cases, the camera and models are in the same situation.